# Red hat linux broadcast IP address

Tags: linux, ip-address, redhat

I am working with 4 different servers. When I run `ifconfig` on them, they all have the same Bcast IP address.

I am trying to Access each individual server with a different broadcast IP address.

Here is the `ifconfig` output for one of the servers:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:B6:5D:DF  
      inet addr:172.17.100.233  Bcast:172.17.103.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12032390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11808161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1372473451 (1.2 GiB)  TX bytes:1902411861 (1.7 GiB)
```

Is there a way to change the broadcast IP address on each individual server?

Comment: You can not, broadcast address is defined by the size of the IP network. If all 4 servers are on the same subnet, they will all have the same broadcast. Why would you want to change it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can not, broadcast address is defined by the size of the IP network. If all 4 servers are on the same subnet, they will all have the same broadcast. The whole purpose of a `broadcast` address is to, uhm, broadcast :) packets to all the hosts on the subnet, not to address individual hosts.

Comment: I am using scala and simple build tool. Simple build tool requires a broadcast ip address. But I only want to broadcast the program to two of the servers. Is there a way to change the broadcast ip address for two of the servers?

Comment: Nope, you can not and should not. Or well, you _can_, but it won't work they way you intend it to. Depending on your tool and its configuration I might be able to advise a particular implementation,b ut I'll need more details - what tool is used to start with.

Comment: Simple build tool is being used, along with akka actors and scala. Does the broadcast ip address spread the load evenly between servers, or does it broadcast the the packets to all servers? I really want to just broadcast the packets to two of the servers, and spread the load evenly between those two servers. Akka actors requires a broadcast ip address, and the actual ip address doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered using Akka routing? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/routing.html